# How to hide the folder tree from users

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created my website in php and I would like to hide the arboressence to my users.
For example to login, the link is mysite.com/views/users/login.php and the form goes to mysite.com/forms/login.php

I would like to hide this for the user, for example, to connect the link would be mysite.com/login/

I have to create a router? or does it have nothing to do?

All will be done on the file Htaccess with rules of rewriting? or there are other ways? (I have thirty pages to rewrite as mysite.com/views/exports/new_export.php)

So I would like to know what is the best way to rewrite the links

Answer (score -1):

Make a .htaccess file and paste the following code in it then put it in the root directory of you srver ... it will do the job

```
#AddDefaultCharset charset=utf-8
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

redirect 301 /views/users/login.php /login/
RewriteRule ^/login/$ views/users/login.php
```

repeat the last line and modify it for each URL you want

Comment: Thanks but how can i make the views/users/login.php page no longer accessible or return the user directly to /login/

Comment: add this line ... it will do it....
redirect 301 /views/users/login.php /login/

Comment: No, if user have this link views/users/login.php He can access to the page without any error

Comment: I updated my code ... do exactly like it .. it should work

Comment: in this example if any body try to access /account.php he will be redirected to /cms/account.php

Comment: Thank you but Chrome give me this error :ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: i think you have other lines in your htacces file causing this error ... delete any other code and test with my code only ... it is working fine with me.

Comment: I deleted any other code and I have another error "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /C:/wamp/www/mysite/views/users/login.php on this server."

Comment: the problem in you in your server try to fix it ... but the code is 100% correct

Comment: Ok thank you and how I can do It with dynamic link rules like : RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /views/users/$1.php [L]

Comment: make a separate question for this with more details...